# expression() command in R with semicolons

Tags: r, curve

In the output of the following code,

```
curve((1+exp(-1*x))^-1,
    xlim=c(-10,10),ylim=c(0,1),
    main="Logistic function",xlab=expression ("x"[t-d]),
    ylab=expression ("G"("x"[t-d],gamma,c)))
```

In the y-axis label, how to place a semi-colon in between immediately before the gamma instead of a comma?

Answer (score 2):

In this case you just need to think of the semicolon as text rather than a special character you can do

```
ylab=expression ("G"("x"[t-d]~";"~gamma,c))
```

or you can use `*` rather than `~` if you want less space.